# Python. Deleting mulitple values from different

Tags: python, pandas

I have a number of columns where I need to delete "-" entries from the DataFrame.

I have looked up documentation with possible solutions, however everyone emphasize is done only on 1 column at a time. Is there any other method for a bigger scale, rather than replicating it?

Thank you in advance.

```
df['Column'] = df['Column'].replace('-', np.nan)
df = df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['Column'])
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample? Or need output like  `df = df.replace('-', np.nan)` and `df = df.dropna()` ?

Comment: `df = df.dropna(axis=0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
df.replace('-', np.nan).dropna(axis=0)
```